# SharePoint Add-In not working with Azure App Service Authentication: CSRF issue

Tags: azure, authentication, sharepoint, csrf

I have a SharePoint Add-In hosted in an Azure Web App. After turning on the App Service Authentication (Azure AD is the authentication provider), I got a HTTP 403 status when accessing the Add-In from a SharePoint site.

For those that doesn't know how the authentication and authorization flow works in a provider-hosted SharePoint Add-In, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142382.aspx).

When SharePoint sends the POST request with the context token to the Azure Web App, the IIS module 'EasyAuthModule_32bit' considers this as a threat (Cross-site request forgery). The origin of the request is [tenant].sharepoint.com and the domain of the Azure Web App is [webapp].azuresites.net.

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148102/cannot-get-basic-sharepoint-online-add-in-to-show-provider-hosted-mvc-page) a user in stackoverflow with the same error but i guess he never figured out it was related with the Authentication / Authorization settings.

**Is there any way to configure this module in order to allow the requests that are coming from an specific domain (e.g. *.sharepoint.com)?**

Comment: Have you tested the web-app on localhost and see with Fiddler to get more info with the requests in terms of headers, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the Failed Request Logging in Azure in order to get a more detailed view of the request that was being blocked by the IIS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *.sharepoint.com to allowed origins under CORS setting on the Azure portal for your app service.  More information on enabling CORS setting on azure app service can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript)